# Peeling paint on Window Sill

Tags: paint, outdoor, repainting, primer, paint-removal

First DIY project so please excuse my ignorance. How should I fix peeling paint on a window sill - is the process: scrape off the paint, primer and paint?

What is a paint and primer that is resistant to the outdoor Los Angeles heat?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> is the process: scrape off the paint, primer and paint?

Yes, with the possible exception that you missed a step between scrape & primer: Repair any wood damage you may find.

How to do the wood repair will depend on the damage you find and you're free to ask a whole new question if/when you do find some. (Please be sure to search the site first, there are loads of questions about repairing outdoor wood damage, and you'll probably find there's already an answer for you.)

The most important part of any paint job is the preparation work you do. Make sure you remove any and all loose material. If you don't, the best paint in the world, applied with the utmost care, will have an excellent bond to loose material that will fall off next week anyway. You *must* give the new primer/paint something solid to hold on to.

As to what paint to use - product recommendations are off-topic. In general<sup>*</sup>, though, when purchasing paint you get what you pay for. Buy a quality primer & paint from a reputable brand and you'll be fine.

---

<sup>*</sup>I do know a person who spent the better part of $100/gallon to purchase a clothing designer branded paint for his office. I don't know how long the paint lasted in comparison to non-designer brand paint, but, it's what he wanted and he had the cash to burn, so it didn't matter to him. This is *not* what I'm talking about when I say "you get what you pay for".

Comment: Wonder if they are the same people who buy plus 900$  pair of jeans.  Miss the old days before people started slapping designer label on stuff.

Comment: The funny thing, @crip659, is that products and services are worth exactly what people are willing to pay for them. If nobody was willing to pay $900 for a pair of jeans, they wouldn't sell and the price would come down...

Comment: Did a remodel for a disabled lady who had gotten a grant from the county to cover costs, she insisted on using Ralph Lauren paint throughout the house. Absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: If she chose to spend money there instead of other places, @matt., what difference does it make? Unless she wasn't making cutbacks elsewhere...

Comment: @FreeMan As far as I know the money was to be used to make ADA improvements, wider doors, wheel chair ramp, accessible shower stall, etc and she skimped on quite a few changes that she had proposed to get the grant which to me seemed like a bait/switch to the county.

Comment: Would you guys recommend oil based paint or acrylic paint for outdoor use?

Comment: No, we wouldn't make such a recommendation. These days, latex paints are (theoretically) just as good as oil. There's not much to choose between them, so go with the one that floats your boat.